# Подсчёт длины массива

Tags: массивы

Есть массив x = [1,2,3.....n]

Нужно узнать длину массива.
Массивы создаются как в python (сколь душе угодно и без всяких пробоем)
Массивы можно сравнивать между собой на предмет равенства по количеству элементов, возвращается тру или фолс.
Вызов не существующего элемента массива приводит к краху программы.
Пустой массив существует x = []
Массивы можно суммировать и добавлять элементы через оператор ++ (просто принять как данность)
Можно делать срез массива.
Рекурсия - разрешена.

Циклы - отсутствуют
Стандартных функций определения длины массива нет.
Указателей нет.

Comment: ЗБС... а что есть-то? ну кроме гарантированного способа обвалить программу, конечно...

Comment: Можно сравнивать массивы, складывать их, делать срезы массивов

Comment: Массив может быть пустой и это не ошибка (x = []) и его можно сравнивать с другими массивами

Comment: Полный список операций, с пояснениями - в вопрос. Например, *сравнивать массивы* - что это значит? что сравнивается - длины, элементы, ключи? что получаем в результате? ну и т.п.

Comment: Равенство по количеству элементов, на самом деле я и сам хз, так как не сказано в задаче, просто сказано, массивы можно сравнивать на выходе тру или фолс

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def lenx(x, curlen = 0):
  if ( x == [] ):
    return curlen
  else:
    return lenx(x[0:-1],curlen + 1)

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(lenx(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getsize(arr[]) 
{
    declare tmp[];
    declare one[1:1];
    declare count=0;
    while not (tmp = arr)
        tmp.add one;
        count++;
    end while;
    return count;
}
```

Comment: К сожалению про while тоже ничего не сказано в условиях, наверное, автор задачи, предполагает, что while нет, не зря он делает акцент на вызове самовызове функции ( рекурсии )

Comment: @me-andrej-al Ну a какая в пень разница? вместо WHILE будет рекурсивный самовызов - суть-то не изменится... просто придётся передавать больше параметров или делать их глобальными.

Comment: Хорошо, идею я понял, спасибо

Comment: @me-andrej-al Т.е. равны - возвращаем результат, иначе плюсадын и самовызов.